# How to implement an advanced Javascript content slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm a designer in charge of implementing a horizontal JS slider similar to the follow mockup (press the right and left arrow buttons to see what I'm aiming for):

http://hovenftp.com/spinscroll/scroll1.html
(it may take some time to load)

I've done a lot of Googling to find a library that I can tweak to achieve something similar, but I've had no luck. My JS skills are woefully lacking, so I'm not sure where to even get started on building it from scratch. I'm guessing something involving absolute positioning and conditionals could handle the movement of the blue selector, but the albums need to scroll left and right too.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about [bxslider](http://bxslider.com)? Check [Examples -> Multiple slides at once](http://bxslider.com/examples/display-move-multiple-slides-once-example-one)

Comment: I'm actually using bxslider right now. It doesn't do everything I need it to do though. While sliding the albums left and right is taken care of, moving the blue "selector" isn't doable.

Comment: How is the blue selector supposed to work? Can't you just style it as css on hover?

Comment: The blue selector is supposed to start on #1, and move to #2 when clicking on the right arrow. Then #3, then the albums slide to left by 1, then #4, then #5.

Comment: Well, I'm sure it's possible just not by default. Use `moveSlideQty: 1` and `onBeforeSlide: function(){}` and then try to cook some custom code from there.

Answer (score 0):

well the html structure is like this;

```
div.viewport -> wrapping the whole slide and defining the 'viewport' of your slider
    div.slider -> this wraps all the single images and has a width of 900000px
        div.img -> this wraps the actual image and has a blue border on 'selected'
        div.img -> another
        div.img -> and another..
```

your javascript would count the div.img and calculate the div.slider width. You would then always check to see if the active div.img is within the div.viewport, if not, set the div.slider's left or margin-left style, so that its in the viewport. Thats how I've developed the sliders for the newscompany I work for (www.20min.ch)

Answer (score 0):

I like using [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) for stuff like this. Lightweight, well-documented and easy to customize to suit your needs.

Comment: I use Cycle on a lot of my projects. While it can handle the horizontal cycling of album covers, I still need something that can move the blue "selector" square too.